# Using the JQuery Autotab plugin, is it possible to create a field that accepts exactly 6 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working with the [Autotab JQuery plugin](http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/)

Here's an example they give in the Autotab documentation...

Regular Expression (Allows numbers and periods)

```
$('#regex').autotab({ format: 'custom', pattern: '[^0-9\.]' });
```

The weird thing is that the pattern is a set of characters negated by the caret (^).  So I assume the way this works is that the pattern specifies characters that the user isn't allowed to enter.

I was trying to create a field that could be left blank by the user, or would accept six and only six (no more, no less) digits.  Is this more complex than Autotab allows?

Comment: then  add the anchors like `'^[^0-9.]{6}$'`

Comment: I think you set the max length either in the autotab function or in the input element. So, `$('#regex').autotab('filter', { format: 'custom', pattern: '[^0-9\.]', maxlength: 6 });` would work. As far as the filter, it is a single char filter applied to each character when entered. And it looks like it's a `not allowed` negative filter though.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj - I tried that.  It doesn't appear to support anchors in the pattern.  I also don't think it supports {6} either.

Comment: @ sln - maxlength works to set a maxiumum length, but it doesn't enforce a minimum.  So the user could still enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 characters.  I need it to be 6 or nothing.  I'm beginning to suspect that autotab cannot do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is to limit to only 6 characters you can create a range, this way you should solve the problem ...

```
$('#regex').autotab({ format: 'custom', pattern: '[^0-9+$]', maxlength: 6, minlength: 6});
```